# Converting kwargs into variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, eval

How do I convert kwargs objects into local variables?
I am a math teacher and I want to write a helper function where I can use JS-style template strings to write problems.

I want to do something like this:

```
TemplateString('{{a*b}} apples are shared among {{a}} children. How many apples do each child get?', {'a': 3, 'b': 5})
//return '15 apples are shared among 3 children...'
```

I am going to search for '{{}}' in strings and call eval() on what is inside that. But first I need to convert {'a': 3, 'b': 5} into local variables a=3 and b=5. The variables could be int, float or str. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is your dictionary always have 2 elements, `a` and `b`? If so, just simply do `int(dict['a'])*int(dict['b'])`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning to use `eval`, you don't need to convert them to locals at all. [`eval` takes optional `globals` and/or `locals` arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) that defines the active scope variables for that expression. If you provide `globals` (the second positional argument) and not `locals` (the third), then `globals` is reused as `locals`, so for example:

```
>>> eval('a * b', {'a': 5, 'b': 3})
15
```