# Setting **kwargs as local variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, eval, local-variables

I wanted to receive some arguments via `**kwargs` and convert them to local variables. So I first tried like this:

```
for k, v in kwargs.items():
    cmd = k + ' = ' + stringify(v)
    exec(cmd)
```

Which ... somehow did not work. Trying to figure out why, at some point I had this example:

```py
def stringify(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return "'" + s + "'"
    else:
        return str(s)


def print_var(local):
    print(local)


def test_func(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        cmd = k + " = " + stringify(v)
        print(cmd)
        exec(cmd)
    print()

    print("locals: " + str(locals()))
    print()

    print("--- locals()['var']:")
    print(locals()["foo"])
    print(locals()["bar"])
    print(locals()["baz"])
    print()

    print("--- eval")
    print(eval("foo"))
    print(eval("bar"))
    print(eval("baz"))
    print()

    print("--- exec")
    exec("print_var(foo); print_var(bar); print_var(baz)")
    print()

    try:
        foo
    except NameError as e:
        print("NameError:", e)

    try:
        print_var(foo)
    except NameError as e:
        print("NameError:", e)

    try:
        bar
    except NameError as e:
        print("NameError:", e)

    try:
        print_var(bar)
    except NameError as e:
        print("NameError:", e)

    try:
        baz
    except NameError as e:
        print("NameError:", e)

    try:
        print_var(baz)
    except NameError as e:
        print("NameError:", e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    kwargs = {"foo": 13, "bar": True, "baz": "whatever"}
    test_func(**kwargs)
```

When executing, I get the following result (Python 3.6.9 in a virtualenv)

```
foo = 13
bar = True
baz = 'whatever'

locals: {'cmd': "baz = 'whatever'", 'v': 'whatever', 'k': 'baz', 'kwargs': {'foo': 13, 'bar': True, 'baz': 'whatever'}, 'foo': 13, 'bar': True, 'baz': 'whatever'}

--- locals()['var']:
13
True
whatever

--- eval
13
True
whatever

--- exec
13
True
whatever

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
NameError: name 'baz' is not defined
NameError: name 'baz' is not defined
```

And ... I don't get why. Why are the variables not available locally, even though they seem to be in the `locals`, and can be used by `exec` and `eval`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710674/converting-kwargs-into-variables) answer suggests a way if I'm okay with using `eval` - Though I'd like to avoid using it.

It was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/any-way-to-modify-locals-dictionary) that locals are optimized as an array at runtime in Python 3. The [linked](https://bugs.python.org/issue4831) thread gives slightly more clarity about it as well - though according to it, locals will not be modified. However, this clearly (?) happened here.

So my assumption is: for some reason, two `locals` exist, one is probably an array and was created at 'compile'-time, and the other one (the one I'm modifying with `exec`) is probably an actually dynamic dict. And that while the new, dynamic one is accessible from `eval` and `exec`, for some reason it will not be considered when trying to resolve variables 'normally'.

So I guess my questions are:

- Where did I go wrong?
- Which part of 'local variable' did I misunderstand? How is it different in modules?
- Where can I find more information about this behaviour?
- Is there a different way to use variables passed via `**kwargs` as local variables without resorting to `eval` when calling them?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Your attempts at printing your `exec`-created variables is failing because the variable references are being interpreted as globals (which genuinely don't exist).  A variable reference cannot be compiled as a reference to a local unless such a local exists at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `**kwargs` variables from a method call with something like this:

```
def printfoo(foo=None, **kwargs):
    print(f"foo is {foo}")

def printa(a=None, **kwargs):
    print(f"a is {a}")

def printall(**kwargs):
    printfoo(**kwargs)
    printa(**kwargs)

print("Only foo variable is set:")
printall(foo="bar")
printall(**{"foo": "bar"})

print("\nOnly a variable is set:")
printall(a=5)

print("\nfoo and a variable are set:")
printall(**{"foo": "barrrrrr", "a":999})
```

Resulting output:

```
Only foo variable is set:
foo is bar
a is None
foo is bar
a is None

Only a variable is set:
foo is None
a is 5

foo and a variable are set:
foo is barrrrrr
a is 999
```

In the code I directly address the variables by their name `foo` and `a` (in the f-strings).

Comment: Your approach certainly works - and while I will probably do it like this (If no other answer shows up), I was looking for a 'more direct' way - without having to add `**kwargs` to all functions down the line. Thanks for your help!